# How to move all files to a parent folder while not breaking links in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My site's files are kept in `root/somefolder/` 
I want to select all files in somefolder and move to root, effectively getting rid of unnecessary somefolder.

Every time I select files in VSCode Explorer and drag them up to root, they want to drop in any other folder but not in the root.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is confusing behavior.

In order for this to work just drop your selected files somewhere in the empty space in the Explorer panel below all other files. The whole area will be highlighted to indicate that you are about to drop the files into the root directory.